I have almost correct but not quiet code in Python for computing chess endgame with nonstandard pieces on the board
My problem is that the code doesn't correctly handle 3 nor 4 pieces on the board.
The code is here at pastebin:
xkwDAZEc
I would like to have it fixed.
My problem is that the code doesn't correctly handle 3 nor 4 pieces on the board.
The code is here:
I would like to have it fixed. Or at least to obtain a suggestion where I can find help.
I was trying kaggle but it didn't work.
But the code does handle kK correctly but not , say kKQ nor AkK.
Once fixed, I can offer around 100$

If you want help here, the relevant, run-able, code must be in the question itself along with inputs, if any, and a full explanation of the expected and actual behaviors.

@500-InternalServerError I tried to post the code but it cannot be saved because of this error: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 35718. This is the input:    start_fen = "8/7k/8/8/8/1K6/8/1Q6 w - - 0 1" and it should output 1000,-999,998,-997,996,.... It even prints a board with one king only as an intermediate position !!

Code should be the minimal code necessary to reproduce the error. Sorry to say, but it is your task to reduce the code to that minimum in preparation of posting here.

@trincot I think that the code is almost minimal already. I'm not sure which part of that code makes the error. So deleting that part would make the error undetectable.

@JanPax Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

@Progman I have explained why I cannot reduce the size of my question's code.And hence I cannot include the code of that question of mine because it exceeds the allowed size of the input.

@JanPax You should [edit] your question to be focus on a specific problem, which can be shown with a MCVE, not ask a generic general debug question of a 900 line program. Please see: Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?.
